# PyQt5 delete a QListWidgetItem when button in widget is pressed

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a `listWidget` that contains multiple `QListWidgetItem` and for simplicity's sake, let's assume that each `QListWidgetItem` consists of a `QWidget` with a `QPushButton` called `delete`. This is assembled with this code:

```
class widgetItem(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(widgetItem, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('UIfiles/trainingWidget.ui', self) # Load the .ui file

        self.listWidgetItem = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidgetItem.setSizeHint(self.sizeHint())
        self.delete.clicked.connect(self.deleteSelf)
        parent.listWidget.addItem(self.listWidgetItem)
        parent.listWidget.setItemWidget(self.listWidgetItem, self)
```

and this is called in the main app with this:

```
def additem(self):
    self.referenceDict[self.itemID] = widgetItem(self)
```

Now, my goal is to delete this particular widget from both the referenceDict as well as the listWidget when the button is pressed. Each widgetItem also has their own itemID as a string, and can access the listWidget as well as the referenceDict. How do I write this `deleteSelf?` I've tried using `self.deleteLater` but it seems like it only deletes the `QWidget` but not the `QListWidgetItem`. Calling `self.listWidgetItem.deleteLater` raises an attribute error as it cannot be deleted this way. I also tried `parent.referenceDict.pop(self.itemID)` but for some reason it raises a key error despite both the keys matching when I printed the dict out.

Comment: @Alexander what would be a better method to add stuff to a listWidget? I noticed that you cannot directly add widgets into a listWidget, you have to make a listWidgetItem first , add the listWidgetItem to the list and then add the widget into the listWidgetItem. I also was wondering if my method of saving the widgets to a dictionary to avoid garbage collection was good practice, or if there was a more standard way of storing n number of widgets.

Comment: @Alexander I tried the answer you gave, however the issue is that I need a delete button for each individual item widget and `listWidget.currentIndex().row()` selects the currently selected widget, not the widget that the delete button is supposed to delete. I suppose what I should do is to set the focus of the listWidget to the widget with the button, but then I run into the same issue of trying to find out the index of the widget in question within the listWidget.

Comment: @ChronoVortex [`deleteLater()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#deleteLater) is a function of QObject, QListWidgetItems are *not* QObjects. Storing the widgets in a dictionary is not necessary (and potentially dangerous) because as soon as they are set on the view, they will *not* be garbage collected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove listitems using the `takeItem` method and delete widgets using the `deleteLater` method.

I wasn't to fond of your chosen process for creating the widgets and adding them to the list, so I went ahead and created a minimal example but using `QPushButton` instead of QWidgets for the itemWidgets.

Example:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.listWidget = QListWidget(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.listWidget)
        self.addListItems()

    def addListItems(self):           # creates the item widgets
        for _ in range(5):
            item = QListWidgetItem(type=0)
            widget = ListItem("button", self, item)
            self.listWidget.addItem(item)
            self.listWidget.setItemWidget(item, widget)

    def removeWidgetItem(self, item):  # removes the item widgets
        index = self.listWidget.indexFromItem(item).row()
        item = self.listWidget.takeItem(index)

class ListItem(QPushButton):

    def __init__(self, text, parent, item):
        super().__init__(text, parent)
        self.item = item                     # the ListWidgetItem
        self._parent = parent                # the Window
        self.clicked.connect(self.deleteSelf)

    def deleteSelf(self):                    # slot for button click
        self._parent.removeWidgetItem(self.item)
        self.deleteLater()

app = QApplication([])
window = Window()
window.show()
app.exec()
```